# Access to image at [Img Link] from origin [domain] has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, vue.js, nginx, server

I have a domain, domain.com where I have hosted my VueJs application and I have a domain api.domain.com where I have hosted my Django API. I have hosted both of these applications on the AWS (EC2 ubuntu instance).
I am getting this Image CORS error while I am sending `add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'  '*' always;` in the NGINX.conf

```
Access to image at 'http://api.deshpardesh.in/media/newspapers/images_qseNU9o.jpeg' from origin 'http://deshpardesh.in' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Here is the actual error.

Comment: Can you share how you are adding the header in the nginx config?

Comment: location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin * always;
    }

Comment: I don't think the "always" part needs to be added to the header

Comment: Nginx has to be compiled with 
 http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html

Answer (score 1):

There were two issues for me.

One is that nginx only processes the last add_header it spots down a tree. So if you have an add_header in the server context, then another in the location nested context, it will only process the add_header directive inside the location context. Only the deepest context.

From the NGINX docs on add_header:

There could be several add_header directives. These directives are inherited from the previous level if and only if there are no add_header directives defined on the current level.

Second issue was that the location / {} block I had in place was actually sending nginx to the other location ~* (.php)$ block (because it would repath all requests through index.php, and that actually makes nginx process this php block). So, my add_header directives inside the first location directive were useless, and it started working after I put all the directives I needed inside the php location directive.

Finally, here's my working configuration to allow CORS in the context of an MVC framework called Laravel (you could change this easily to fit any PHP framework that has index.php as a single entry point for all requests).

```
server {
    root /path/to/app/public;
    index index.php;

    server_name test.dev;

    # redirection to index.php
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

        # With php5-fpm:
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;

        # cors configuration
        # whitelist of allowed domains, via a regular expression
        # if ($http_origin ~* (http://localhost(:[0-9]+)?)) {
        if ($http_origin ~* .*) { # yeah, for local development. tailor your regex as needed
             set $cors "true";
        }

        # apparently, the following three if statements create a flag for "compound conditions"
        if ($request_method = OPTIONS) {
            set $cors "${cors}options";
        }

        if ($request_method = GET) {
            set $cors "${cors}get";
        }

        if ($request_method = POST) {
            set $cors "${cors}post";
        }

        # now process the flag
        if ($cors = 'trueget') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        }

        if ($cors = 'truepost') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        }

        if ($cors = 'trueoptions') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';

            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000; # cache preflight value for 20 days
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,Content-Type,Accept,Origin,User-Agent,DNT,Cache-Control,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since';

            add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
            return 204;
        }
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/test.dev.error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/test.dev.access.log;
}
```

The gist for the above is at: https://gist.github.com/adityamenon/6753574